# Вызвано исключение по адресу ... : нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу

Tags: c++, исключения, доступ

При отладке:

Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00332036 в Project.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000000.

Это связанно с тем, что pBegin и pNext определены в разных классах?
И `Class1* pBegin;` определён в классе Class2? Тип-то у него всё равно Class1.
С чем связано исключение и как можно исправить?

```
class Class1 {

private:
    Class1 *pPrev; 
    Class1 *pNext;
```

```
class Class2 { 

private:
    Class1* pBegin;
```

Двусвязный список.

pBegin – начало списка

pNext – следующий элемент

pPrev – предыдущий элемент

т.к. они приватные, используются через get и set.

Ф-ция, в которой вылетает ошибка:

```
void Class2::Add_to_Beginning(Class1& client) { // ф-ции для постановки элемента в начало списка
    
    
    Class1* pv = new Class1 (client); // выделяем память под новый элемент 
    
    
    pv->setPNext(getPBegin()); // тут ошибка. Нарушение парв доступа Q___Q
      // связь вправо от нового элемента к начальному 
    
    getPBegin()->setPPrev(pv); // связь влево от начального эл-та к новому

    pv = getPBegin(); // новый элемент теперь начальный
```

Class1:

```
class Class1 {

private:

    Class1 *pPrev; // указатель на предыдущий элемент
    Class1 *pNext; // указатель на следующий элемент

public:

    Class1(); 
    Class1(char* car_make, int bill_number, char* car_number);

    void setPNext(Class1* pointer) { pNext = pointer; }
    void setPPrev(Class1* pointer) { pPrev = pointer; }

    Class1* getPNext() { return pNext; }
    Class1* getPPrev() { return pPrev; }
};
```

Class2:

```
class Class2 { 

private:
    Class1* pBegin; // начало списка
    Class1* pEnd; // конец списка
    
public:

    Class2 () {
        pBegin = NULL;
        pEnd = NULL;
    }

    ~Class2() {
        if (pBegin != NULL)
            delete pBegin;
        if (pEnd != NULL)
            delete pEnd;
    }

    void Add_to_the_Beginning(Class1& client);

    Class1* getPBegin() { return pBegin; }
    Class1* getPEnd() { return pEnd; }
};
```

P.S. Если нужно что-то добавить - напишите, пожалуйста. Большую часть кода удалила, чтобы не перегружать вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это вызвано тем что твой указатель не инициализирован и равен нулю, то есть он никуда не указывает, когда ты пытаешься им воспользоваться он естественным образом пытается прочитать нулевую ячейку после чего программа умирает в муках.